# How to get a values list from a dictionary where the key matches in a list in c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to retrieve all the values list from the dictionary based on a condition on the key, i.e. I want to retrieve only the values for which the respective key matches in alist.

**Example:** dictionary is as follows

```
IDictionary<string, string> maskingValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
maskingValues.Add("cat", "Me@ena");
maskingValues.Add("dog", "N&avya");
maskingValues.Add("llama", "vivek!a");
maskingValues.Add("iguana", "sh^ams");
```

and I have list of strings as

```
List<string> keysString = new List<string>();
keysString.Add("cat");
keysString.Add("fox");
```

Now my requirement is to get the values list from the dictionary where the key matches from the keysString list.

The output should be

```
Me@ena
```

till now what I have done is

```
var all_parameters = maskingValues .Keys.ToList();

var parameters_to_mask = all_parameters.Intersect(keysString);

var values_list = parameters_to_mask.Where(k => data_dictionary.ContainsKey(k)).Select(k => data_dictionary[k]);
```

so  `values_list` will contain the output `Me@ena`, I retrieved all the keys from the dictionary and then compared the keys list with the `keysString` list and then retrieved the values list from the output of the two list's intersect. But can I do it in more optimized way so that the code and the performance is good.

Thanks in advance. Please help me out.

Comment: Show how you did it! What you did may have been good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions. This one for example:

```
var newlist = maskingValues.Where(x => keysString.Contains(x.Key)).Select(y=>y.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
var q = maskingValues.Where(x => keysString.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: you could use `Select`, so the `item.Value` is not necessary

Comment: why not just keysString.Contains(x.Key) ?

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa - `keysString` is a list.

Comment: @Sadiq Exactly!

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa - Ah! now i know why - i changed it to `==` to for exact match `Contains` maybe give other keys in Dictionary.

Comment: @Sadiq I mean you could do it like this: maskingValues.Where(x => keysString.Contains(x.Key));

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa - silly me... i had a hard time understanding something simple sorry about that. Got you finally.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a quick bit of code to do this fully using linq.

```
keysString.Where(x => maskingValues.Keys.Contains(x)).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(maskingValues[x]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got the spec right but this is faster than linq:

```
var matches = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in keysString)
{
    if (maskingValues.TryGetValue(key, out string value))
    {
        matches.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary is large, you can improve performance by taking advantage of the fact that accessing an element by key in a dictionary is O(

```
var result = keysString
    .Select(k => 
          { string value; 
            maskingValues.TryGetValue(k, out value); 
            return value; 
          })
    .Where(v => v != null);
```

... etc ...

Note that using `TryGetValue` is more efficient than calling `Contains` then the dictionary indexer.

Answer (score -1):

This Should Work:

Below Solution is used when you know your Key name and want to retrive value of key

```
string objectValue;
maskingValues.TryGetValue("cat", out objectValue);
```

If you want to Retrive All values from Dictionary than used single line of code: `maskingValues.Values`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. This is just general obtaining a value by key from the dictionary....